# Remove white space from the json data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have script that fetch the data from the database. These data is in multidimensional array. You can say array of array and the out put is encoded in json format. 
My question is how to remove white space from the beginning and the end of each json value.

Output is:-

```
 {"post":{"id":"4","image":" LIVE_3.JPG ","video":"LIVE_3.MOV","category":""}},
 {"post":{"id":"3","image":" LIVE_2.JPG ","video":"LIVE_2.MOV","category":""}},
 {"post":{"id":"2","image":"LIVE_1.JPG","video":"LIVE_1.MOV","category":""}}
```

Needed and expected:-

```
{"post":{"id":"4","image":"LIVE_3.JPG ","video":"LIVE_3.MOV","category":""}},
{"post":{"id":"3","image":"LIVE_2.JPG ","video":"LIVE_2.MOV","category":""}},
{"post":{"id":"2","image":"LIVE_1.JPG","video":"LIVE_1.MOV","category":""}}
```

My code is:-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data  ORDER BY ID DESC ";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

/* create one master array of the records */
$posts = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);


    }
}

/* output in necessary format */

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));




/* disconnect from the db */
@mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is the function you need

Comment: Anyway I would suggest trimming this data when you first insert it. Then the problem is fixed once forever. If that's not possible, then either trim it using mysql in your SELECT statement or trim it using PHP when you read it. Lots of ways. Did you research or try anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) to remove the spaces, however it's better to validate & sanitize your data before inserting it into database

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $post['image'] = trim($post['image']);
        $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
    }
}
```

PS. please stop using `mysql_*` extension immediately, it's dead and already emoved from PHP7.x , so your code should be something like:-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data  ORDER BY ID DESC ";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

/* create one master array of the records */
$posts = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $post['image'] = trim($post['image']);
        $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to edit your connection from mysql_* to mysqli_*

Comment: Note @ADyson's comment on the question; **do not use `mysql_`**. This answers the question, using the existing code, but should be re-written for production using the [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: @JustCarty yes, sure

Comment: yes i will do that.. This function is removing space from only images . I want it to remove if it is there in video or id or category

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed feel free to use the function with any other array element.

Comment: I am just confused...hassan with your help I am able to remove white space from images but there is a bunch of data that contain whitespace in videos id and category.

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed you can use the trim function which is trimming the whitespaces -if the second parameters is not defined- so you can use it as we did with the `$post['image'] = trim($post['image'])`